# How does the scope of javascript variables work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the scope of variables in javascript when it comes to web-pages.
For example, if I have let's say an index.html and I define two scripts

**script One**

```
var x = 2
```

**script Two**

```
var y = x
```

Would this work? Do both scripts work from a global pool of variables or are they each given their own space to work in?

Comment: Yes, both scripts are executed in the same, global scope.

Comment: Can't believe they just closed this question while I was writing this huge response. [***I created this explanatory demo for you.***](http://pastebin.com/VanDPbwn)

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, thank you. Sorry about it being closed!